# Check XML Values from different Parents and replace value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a situation and I need some hits to develop it:

The XML is big I will include some parts only:

```
<root>
    <header></header>
    <EventList>
        <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList />
            <biz>AAA</biz>
            <extension>
                <MATNR>1</MATNR>
                <PACK_LEVEL>1</PACK_LEVEL>
            </extension>
            <SAPExtension>
                <Attribute>
                    <LOTNO>1</LOTNO>
                </Attribute>
            </SAPExtension>
        </ObjectEvent>
        <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList>
                <epc>2</epc>
            </epcList>
            <biz>AAA</biz>
            <extension>
                <MATNR>1</MATNR>
                <PACK_LEVEL>1</PACK_LEVEL>
            </extension>
            <SAPExtension>
                <Attribute>
                    <LOTNO>1</LOTNO>
                </Attribute>
            </SAPExtension>
        </ObjectEvent>
        <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList>
                <epc>14</epc>
                <epc>11</epc>
                <epc>3</epc>
            </epcList>
            <biz>AAA</biz>
        </ObjectEvent>
        <ObjectEvent>
            <epcList>
                <epc>20</epc>
                <epc>555</epc>
                <epc>32</epc>
                <epc>1</epc>
                <epc>34</epc>
                <epc>34</epc>
                <epc>54</epc>
            </epcList>
            <biz>AAA</biz>
            <extension>
                <MATNR>1</MATNR>
                <PACK_LEVEL>1</PACK_LEVEL>
            </extension>
            <SAPExtension>
                <Attribute>
                    <LOTNO>1</LOTNO>
                </Attribute>
            </SAPExtension>
        </ObjectEvent>
        <AggregationEvent>
            <parentID>1</parentID>
            <readId/>
        </AggregationEvent>
        <AggregationEvent>
            <parentID>3</parentID>
            <readId/>
        </AggregationEvent>
        <AggregationEvent>
            <parentID>2</parentID>
            <readId/>
        </AggregationEvent>
        <AggregationEvent>
            <parentID>4</parentID>
            <readId/>
        </AggregationEvent>
    </EventList>
</root>
```

The xml contains all the time - 4+ = /ObjectEvent and 4 /AggregationEvent

I need to pick up the value of `Aggregation/parentID` and check on the `/ObjectEvent/epcList/Epc[1]` (FIRST POSITION ONLY EXCLUSIVE, if the xml contains the same value but in different then the first Position of epc (ignore)) if equals parentID Value. If Yes and biz equals AAA, I need change the value of one element on /ObjectEvent/disposition with value boolean true

I already develop one xslt, could please check what is missing for that ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ObjectEvent/epcList">
        <xsl:variable name="EPC" select="../epcList/epc[1]" />
        <xsl:for-each select="//AggregationEvent">
            <xsl:variable name="parentID" select="./parentID" />
            <xsl:if test="$parentID=$EPC">
                <xsl:for-each select="//ObjectEvent">
                    <xsl:if
                        test="./epcList/epc=$parentID and ./bizStep=&apos;urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:commissioning&apos;">
                        <xsl:element name="disposition">
                            <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expect result after XSLT logic: (Parent ID contains on epcList\epc (independente of position) and biz equals AAA pick the value from tags and add on AggregationEvent of the relative parentID.

Check the expect result below:

ObjectEvent\epcList\epc contains ( 2 )

```
<ObjectEvent>
    <epcList>
        <epc>20</epc>
        <epc>12</epc>
        <epc>2</epc>
        <epc>0</epc>
    </epcList>
    <biz>AAA</biz>
    <extension>
        <MATNR>1</MATNR>
        <PACK_LEVEL>1</PACK_LEVEL>
    </extension>
    <SAPExtension>
        <Attribute>
           <LOTNO>1</LOTNO>
        </Attribute>
    </SAPExtension>
</ObjectEvent>
```

Aggregation event with parend id = 2 (in this case):

```
<AggregationEvent>
    <parentID>1</parentID>
    <readId/>
</AggregationEvent>
<AggregationEvent>
    <parentID>3</parentID>
    <readId/>
</AggregationEvent>
<AggregationEvent>
    <parentID>2</parentID>
    <readId/>
    <extension>
                <MATNR>1</MATNR>
                <PACK_LEVEL>1</PACK_LEVEL>
            </extension>
            <SAPExtension>
                <Attribute>
                    <LOTNO>1</LOTNO>
                </Attribute>
            </SAPExtension>
</AggregationEvent>
<AggregationEvent>
    <parentID>4</parentID>
    <readId/>
</AggregationEvent>
```

but this disposition on ObjectEvent but not in this position:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuds8.png)

Thanks

Comment: So you want to add a new `disposition` element to the `ObjectEvent` element for which the conditions hold? Or do you want to add the `disposition` elsewhere? As both the "Result" snippet as well as the image you have linked to contain various elements that don't appear at all in the input sample it is hard to understand what the problem is.

Comment: You should reduce your samples to be minimal but complete and well-formed to demonstrate the problem you need help with, then we can help fixing that particular problem. And it should then be possible for you to incorporate the fix into a larger stylesheet or using a larger, more complex XML input. So try to isolate the current problem by posting a minimal but complete and well-formed XML input and XSLT together with output you get and the one you want instead, then we can help fix that.

Comment: Martin, thanks for support, I already fix the xml and requirement, Im coding here its just missing one point now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value of `extension` and `SAPExtension` elements are to be copied to the matching `Aggregation/parentID` only for `ObjectEvent` having value of child element `biz = 'AAA'`, the template needs to be changed as below

```
<xsl:template match="AggregationEvent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:variable name="parentId" select="parentID" />
        <xsl:if test="../ObjectEvent[biz = 'AAA'][epcList/epc = $parentId]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../ObjectEvent[epcList/epc = $parentId]/extension" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../ObjectEvent[epcList/epc = $parentId]/SAPExtension" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The complete XSLT is as below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="AggregationEvent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <xsl:variable name="parentId" select="parentID" />
            <xsl:if test="../ObjectEvent[biz = 'AAA'][epcList/epc = $parentId]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../ObjectEvent[epcList/epc = $parentId]/extension" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../ObjectEvent[epcList/epc = $parentId]/SAPExtension" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the shared input XML, the `epc` values `1` and `2` both are matching with corresponding `parentID` and hence the nodes are appropriately copied.

Please find the working example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwu/1

Comment: Thanks for code I tested but the requirement change - ()

Comment: Use Aggregation Event (Parent ID) and look for a biz=AAA event whose epcList/epc includes the parentID

Get all fields ObjectEvent\Extension\  and ObjectEvent\SAPExtension\ of the parentID

Comment: Please update the sample input XML and corresponding output to make the requirement clearer for understanding.

Comment: Aniket, I just edit your response with one sample of file and what must to do. Thanks for your patience and time.

Comment: I have moved the updated XML and expected output in the question. Going forward, please update the question with the changes instead of adding anything in the provided solution. Thanks.

Comment: Aniket thanks once again, sorry. So I provide everything, I´m really close to finish this but I don´t now how to copy ObjectEvent\extension and \SAPExtension from \ObjectEvent if epcList\epc contains \ParentID and incluse this both structures on \AggregationEvent under <readId/>

Comment: The solution has been updated for the changes to the input XML. If there are any additional changes to the requirements, please open a new question.

Comment: Ankiet ! Brillhant, thanks for help and teach me pretty clear how to work with xslt.  Have nice week.